# Query function unable to use array data range reference

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

#### **Goal:**

I want to optimize the data processing speed of the Query function, which is actually properly functioning, however there are times that it's extremely slow (1-2 minutes). So I'm in the process of improving my entire sheet.
I referred to this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106809/how-can-i-speed-up-google-sheets

With that said, I think I can improve the below Query setup by changing the data range from a regular reference to an array range reference.

#### **How the current query works:**

The below screenshot is a Query function that pulls data from a sheet (Blend Data, which also pulls data from another sheet) and counts the number of statuses (Technical Issue, In Consult, In Progress and Need Info) for each person (agents).

[image]

Here's what I have for the Query function.

```
=QUERY(
    'Blend Data'!$A$3:$C,
    "select C, COUNT(C) where B matches 
    'In Progress|In Consult|Need Info|Technical Issue'
    AND C matches'"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F2,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F3,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F4,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F5,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F6,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"'
    GROUP BY C pivot B",
    1)
```

### **Details about the Query setup:**

- **Blend Data:** Is a sheet in the same spreadsheet that pulls data from 2 sheets within the same spreadsheet, which includes information about the agents and tickets.
- **VLOOKUP:** The "Values!F2" is pulling agent names from a separate sheet in the same spreadsheet. I'd like to use the reference instead of hard coding it as the names can sometimes change.

### **More about the "Blend Data sheet":**

The Blend Data sheet is using the Query function to pull 2 separate sheets ("Sheet A Data" sheet pulling data from a different Spreadsheet, "Sheet B Data" sheet pulling data from a different Spreadsheet) and I was able to do this with the Importrange function. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Here's what I have for the Query function.

```
=QUERY(
    {
        IMPORTRANGE("1DeXTU7dJVJFYIHSP8U9dsKw3YNZVtEZIjbURAd54Xjs","'Sheet A Data'!$A$3:$H");
        IMPORTRANGE("1QUZ-ljkXNOvtnPg-a2FqM2PhYUdt_zX5gMLtB6GcFdc","'Sheet B Data'!$A$3:$H")
    },
    A1,
    1
)
```

#### **Question:**

As mentioned above, I want to change the data to an array format; however, I got an error (Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: C).

Here's what I tried to do.

```
=QUERY(
    {
        IMPORTRANGE("1DeXTU7dJVJFYIHSP8U9dsKw3YNZVtEZIjbURAd54Xjs","'Sheet A Data'!$A$3:$H");
        IMPORTRANGE("1QUZ-ljkXNOvtnPg-a2FqM2PhYUdt_zX5gMLtB6GcFdc","'Sheet B Data'!$A$3:$H")
    },
    "select C, COUNT(C) where B matches 'In Progress|In Consult|Need Info|Blocked By' AND C matches '"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F2,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F3,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F4,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F5,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"|"
    &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F6,Values!F2:F,1,FALSE))&"'
    GROUP BY C pivot B",
  1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use constructed range `{}` you cant use `A,B,C` references in query. instead, you need to use `Col1,Col2,Col3` notation

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1DeXTU7dJVJFYIHSP8U9dsKw3YNZVtEZIjbURAd54Xjs", "Sheet A Data!A3:H");
 IMPORTRANGE("1QUZ-ljkXNOvtnPg-a2FqM2PhYUdt_zX5gMLtB6GcFdc", "Sheet B Data!A3:H")},
 "select Col3,count(Col3) 
  where Col2 matches 'In Progress|In Consult|Need Info|Blocked By' 
    and Col3 matches '"
  &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F2, Values!F2:F, 1, 0))&"|"
  &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F3, Values!F2:F, 1, 0))&"|"
  &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F4, Values!F2:F, 1, 0))&"|"
  &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F5, Values!F2:F, 1, 0))&"|"
  &IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Values!F6, Values!F2:F, 1, 0))&"'
  group by Col3 
  pivot Col2", 1)
```

Comment: Hey @player0, this worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I have one question though. Do you think it's best to always use `Col1, Col2, Col3` notation references? Or is there a time for an `A, B, C` notation reference?

Comment: `A,B,C` is shorter. also with `A,B,C` if you create query with range `A:C` and then decide to change range to `D:F` you need to rewrite whole query argument and change all instances from `A,B,C` to `D,E,F`. but if you wrap the reference into `{}` you can have: `QUERY({A:C}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3")` and now if you wish to change the range for `D:F` you just change it there and you done